# Is there a way to use auth() or other function outside app\Http\Controllers folder?

Tags: php, laravel, responsive-filemanager

I want to use access keys for responsivefilemanager.
Since access keys can be seen by the users(example.com/filemanager/dialog.php?akey=usersaccesskeys), I want the access keys to be temporary(single use only). But I think I need "auth()" and other functions like "User::find($user_id)" to do this. 
Anyways there is an error when I use auth() or controller functions in config file of the filemanager, "Call to undefined function auth() in /path/to/config/config.php".
I am stuck and I don't want to deploy my website like this.
Is there any other ways to make responsivefilemanager secure?

I have also tried using controller php file in app\Http\Controllers\RfmController.php
Other error shows "Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller'"
This is the function RfmController extends to.

I am running LAMP server.
PHP 7.3.7
Laravel 5.8

In my config.php

```
'access_keys' => array(auth()->user()->name),
```

by using controller.php

In my config.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
require('/path/to/app/Http/Controllers/RfmController.php');
$rfm = new RfmController;
.
.
.
'access_keys' => array(RFMClass::rfmakey()),
```

In RfmController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
class RfmController extends Controller
{
    public function rfmakey()
    {
        return auth()->user()->id;
    }
{
```

I expected that rfmakey() would return the username

Answer (score 0):

You need to use middleware. From the [official laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#protecting-routes):

If you are using controllers, you may call the middleware method from the controller's constructor instead of attaching it in the route definition directly:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

As an aside, I would stay away from putting dynamic values or code in my config.php file, like

```
auth()->user()->name
```

This is not a good practice.

Hope this solution helps you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand. Is it okay if I use session values in dialog.php?
I can't think of any other way.